# JavaScript/JQuery change background on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I tried to find a way to make a changeable background image for a one pager. Basically when the user scrolls down to the "About us" section there should be a specific background image for that section, one for "Contact" and so on. It's either that I can't find it or there are not enough examples on the internet on this topic. After reading some questions on Stack Overflow I came up with this code:

```
<style>
    body {
        background-image:url('http://7-themes.com/data_images/out/39/6901356-free-background-images.jpg');
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var image_url = 'http://7-themes.com/data_images/out/39/6901356-free-background-images.jpg';
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 800) {
            image_url = 'http://www.designbolts.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Yellow-blur-background1.jpg';
        }
        $(body).css('background-image', image_url);
    });
</script>
```

It doesn't seem to work and I don't understand why. The website is responsive so the solution should include some explanation at least for making it work on different resolutions.

Comment: I think the syntax should be `$('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + image_url + ')');`. Notice the quotes around `body` and the `url()` around your `image_url`

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that part might be the problem as well. I copied your code and replaced the `$(body).css('background-image', image_url);` part of my script with it. Still wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var image_url = 'http://7-themes.com/data_images/out/39/6901356-free-background-images.jpg';
    console.log($(window).scrollTop());
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 800) {
        image_url = 'http://www.designbolts.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Yellow-blur-background1.jpg';
    }
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + image_url + ')');
    //^^^^^^                          ^^^^^^               ^^^   
});
```

```css
body {
    background-image:url('http://7-themes.com/data_images/out/39/6901356-free-background-images.jpg');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works as intended but how would you handle the responsivity in this case?

Comment: @MateiPanchios I didn't get you question. You mean to keep the background not to scroll with the page?

Comment: No, the website will be responsive, having paragraphs in every section. I'd like to make the background stick to every section while scrolling. I guess I can't control the height of the webpage on every resolution so probably I'd have to target the divs somehow.

Answer (score 1):

incorrect the syntax it should be like this :

```
$('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + image_url + ')');
```

And you can try

```
if($(this).scrollTop() > 800)
```

Comment: can you make  fiddle and post it?

Answer (score 1):

This code works for you (like in the other answers mentoinded):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var image_url = 'http://7-themes.com/data_images/out/39/6901356-free-background-images.jpg';

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 800) {
        image_url = 'http://www.designbolts.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Yellow-blur-background1.jpg';
    }

    $("body").css('background-image', "url('"+image_url+"')");    
});
```

But what if you change your content on the site and the image should not change at 800 pixels but at 900 pixels? For this issue you should not define the 800 pixels hardcoded in your script, but rather use the `$("#whateverSection").offset().top` variable. Look in this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/or977s93/2/)

This way you can easily decide which image you want to show, when a specific section of your site scrolls in.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var image_url = 'default.jpg';

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $("#section1").offset().top) {
        image_url = 'img1.jpg'
    }
    else if ($(window).scrollTop() > $("#section2").offset().top) {
        image_url = 'img2.jpg'
    }
    ...
    else if ($(window).scrollTop() > $("#sectionX").offset().top) {
        image_url = 'imgX.jpg'
    }

    $("body").css('background-image', "url('"+image_url+"')");    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Should work with

```
$('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + image_url + ')');
```

Make sure ur selector is ok

https://jsfiddle.net/js7tadve/